# how to update value in textarea after clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm practicing JavaScript creating a convert case where I have a textarea where the initial text is informed and the second where the converted result should be output, I created a function to invert the text but when I click on the button that calls this function it doesn't convert if there is already a typed text.
How do I get it to update the values ​​when I click on the button?

```js
    function reverseText(){
        function reverse(s){
            var word = '';
            for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            word += s[i];
            return word;
        }
        
        $('#input1').keyup(function(){
            var text = $('#input1').val();
            var newstring = reverse(text);
            $('#input2').val(newstring);
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="convert-case">
       <textarea id='input1'></textarea>
       <textarea id='input2' readonly></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="function-button">
       <button onclick="reverseText()">reverse text</button>
    </div>
```

I want to create other conversion functions so I want the value the user has already typed to be converted as soon as he clicks on one of the conversion options.

Comment: `when I click on the button that calls this function it doesn't convert if there is already a typed text` When you click the button, it will revert the text, then, when you type a key, it will update the input. What exactly do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want the button to directly convert the text. Right now you code is doing the reverse, but update the input only after user type a key.

You want to revert instantly on button click, and keep the update going

```js
    function reverseText(){
        function reverse(s){
            var word = '';
            for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            word += s[i];
            return word;
        }

        function updateInput() {
            var text = $('#input1').val();
            var newstring = reverse(text);
            $('#input2').val(newstring);
        }
        
        $('#input1').keyup(updateInput);
        updateInput();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="convert-case">
       <textarea id='input1'></textarea>
       <textarea id='input2' readonly></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="function-button">
       <button onclick="reverseText()">reverse text</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: or just remove `$('#input1').keyup(updateInput);` if you want to revert only once the button is clicked, and not when the first input is updated

Comment: that's exactly what i was trying to do, now i understood where i had gone wrong.

Comment: @GuilhermeAugusto you will need to accept an answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you want. If you want to get the value from input1, reverse the text and put it into input2 then just remove the first and last line of the code below

```
$('#input1').keyup(function(){
            var text = $('#input1').val();
            var newstring = reverse(text);
            $('#input2').val(newstring);
        });
```